# Rails API login using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, post, curl

I'm building a rails API with authentication and trying to test login using curl. I want to eventually be able to login with a mobile app and retrieve the authentication token. I currently have

```
# api/sessions_controller.rb
class Api::SessionsController < Api::BaseController
   skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

   def create
   @user = User.find_for_authentication(email: params[:email])

   if @user && @user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      @user.generate_authentication_token

         render :json=> {:user_id=>@user.id, :token=>@user.authentication_token}
      else
         error! :unauthenticated
      end
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
   end
end
```

I do a `curl -i -X POST -d "user[email]=user@user.com&user[password]=password" "http://localhost:3000/api/sessions"`

but the login is unsuccessful

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 5d84cbb4-28d3-48fb-bfce-a29d0f40569d
X-Runtime: 0.029000
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.5/2014-11-13)
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 02:29:32 GMT
Content-Length: 61
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; path=/

{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: can you try like this ``curl -i -X POST -d "user[email]='user@user.com'&user[password]='password'" "http://localhost:3000/api/sessions"``

Comment: It still gives the same response

Comment: Try this:  ``curl -i -X POST -d "user[email]=user@user.com" -d "user[password]=password" "http://localhost:3000/api/sessions"``

Comment: Nope, same response still

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following. Your code is referring to the wrong params.

```
   @user = User.find_for_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])

   if @user && @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      @user.generate_authentication_token
```

Comment: Because the params are passed in with in the user hash. For the before code to be actually working you should have send it as ``email=user@user.com&password=password.``, but since we are using ``user[:email]`` we should modify our code to accept ``params[:user][:email]``. Not sure why that modification didn't work. Can you check your rails log to see how the params are being posted?

Comment: `Processing by Api::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"user@user.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms`

Comment: @user3610962 so definitely you should change the params, like i have mentioned. But since its not working something else is blocking it. Can you write ``raise @user`` and see if the user is being found and if that yields a result check ``raise @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])`` see if that yields any result. Using raise will break the execution of the code, but will display the contents of those rails code.

Comment: Ok I kept the params as you suggested. But `raise @user` doesn't yield a result. I still get the same 401 unautorized

Comment: make it the first line after User.find_for_authentication. It should break your code and not complete.

Comment: Yeah, I put it right after the User.find_for_authentication and it still completes. I also tried putting `raise @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])` right after `raise @user` and it completes too but both times I get 401

Comment: Thats not supposed to happen, raise should break and give a 500. Can you check the routes.rb if this create function is the one being called? when we access /api/sessions

Comment: It should be. I have `namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
   resources :customers, :users, :projects, :inventory_items, :inventory_styles, :notes, :attachments
    resources :sessions, only: [:create]
  end`

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure I figured out what my problem was. I had a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in my base_controller that was causing it to not work. Thank you so much for your help! Your answer for correcting my params definitely worked too!